# VS 2010 Load Tests Results with custom counters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, load-testing, performancecounter

I am new on Load Testing (and in general, testing) with visual studio 2010 and I am dealing with several problems.

My question is, is there any way possible, to add a custom test variable on the Load Test Results?

I have the following UnitTest:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    Stopwatch testTimer = new Stopwatch();
    testTimer.Start();
    httpClient.SendRequest();
    testTimer.Stop();

    double requestDelay = testTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
}
```

This UnitTest is used by many LoadTests and I want to add the *requestDelay* variable to the Load Test Result so I can get Min, Max and Avg values like all others Load Test Counters (e.g. Test Response Time).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the link from the @Pritam Karmakar comment and the walkthroughs at the end of my post I finally managed to find a solution.

First I created a [Load Test Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and used the [LoadTestStarting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtest.loadteststarting.aspx) to create my Custom Counter Category and add to it all my counters:

```
void m_loadTest_LoadTestStarting(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{        
    // Delete the category if already exists   
    if (PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("CustomCounterSet"))
    {
        PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("CustomCounterSet");
    }

    //Create the Counters collection and add my custom counters 
    CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
    counters.Add(new CounterCreationData(Counters.RequestDelayTime.ToString(), "Keeps the actual request delay time", PerformanceCounterType.AverageCount64));
    // .... Add the rest counters

    // Create the custom counter category
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("CustomCounterSet", "Custom Performance Counters", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, counters);
}
```

Then, in the `LoadTest` editor I right-clicked on the `Agent CounterSet` and selected *Add Counters...* In the *Pick Performance Counters* window I chose my performance category and add my counters to the CounterSet so the Load Test will gather their data:

[image]

Finally, every UnitTest creates instances of the Counters in the `ClassInitialize` method and then it updates the counters at the proper step:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    PerformanceCounter RequestDelayTime;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext TestContext)
    {
        // Create the instances of the counters for the current test
        RequestDelaytime = new PerformanceCounter("CustomCounterSet", "RequestDelayTime", "UnitTest1", false));
        // .... Add the rest counters instances
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        RequestDelayTime.RawValue = 0;
        RequestDelayTime.EndInit();
        RequestDelayTime.RemoveInstance();
        RequestDelayTime.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
         // ... Testing
         // update counters
         RequestDelayTime.Incerement(time);
         // ... Continue Testing
    }
}
```

Links:

- [Creating Performance Counters Programmatically](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CreatePerformanceCounters.aspx)
- [Setting Performance Counters](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SetPerformanceCounters_2.aspx)
- [Including unit test variable values in load test results](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstswebtest/thread/f1a8d0d1-8d4d-4d2e-b347-226e1dd08b16)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually need is to use:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    TestContext.BeginTimer("mytimer");
    httpClient.SendRequest();
    TestContext.EndTimer("mytimer");
}
```

You can find good documentation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2006/12/15/load-testing-web-services-with-unit-tests.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Never tried this, but I have an idea.

Create 3 class level properties of MAX, MIN and AVG. during each test manipulate those values. And then write all final values once entire load test get executed via Classcleanup or assemblycleanup [test attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You have to run the load test for 1-2 min and have to see which attribute method get called at the end. You can then print those final values in a flat file in local drive via textwriter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it works fine. But it only solves the half part of my problem. Now I want to add those values to the [Load Test Analyzer Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404677.aspx) that VS 2010 automatically generates.

Comment: Please see this link for that details http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstswebtest/thread/f1a8d0d1-8d4d-4d2e-b347-226e1dd08b16