# PerformanceCounterType for average time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, performancecounter

I have created some [Load Tests to an HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990448/vs-2010-load-tests-results-with-custom-counters) which consist of simple `Unit Tests`. Each unit test sends an http request to the server. Now I want to keep some extra information about each load test run so I created customs performance counters.

For example, I have a counter for the timeouts. Every time a timeout occur I `increment` the counter which is of type `NumberOfItems32`, so at the end of the Load Test I can see the total timeouts number.

My problem is that I want to create a counter that will keep the average response time to the http calls. **Which [PerformanceCounterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype.aspx) should I use and how?**

**EDIT**
I thought that the `AverageTimer32` would be the right one to use but the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountertype.aspx) description is:

> Counters of this type display a ratio of the total elapsed time of the sample interval to the number of processes or operations completed during that time

I don't want this. At each unit test run I calculate the response time so I thing that with the appropriate counter only the following code should work:

```
responseTimeCounter.IncrementBy(responseTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for `NumberOfItems32` counter as you want to capture a number.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. It seems that it works like a Sum counter not an Avg. I would like something that every time I call the `IncrementBy` method with the new ResponseTime it will automatically update the Max, Min & Avg values on the Performance Monitor. Is that possible?

Comment: Try `AverageCount64` instead - using performance counters with integration tests looks like not the best idea IMHO. I would just spawn multiple threads in one test.